# I'm trying to compare between a week and the next one in three years in SQL

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I'm trying to calculate a the difference of store visitors between a week and the next one and I'm using a query that calculates this difference only between weeks of the same year and NOT THE LAST WEEK OF A YEAR AND THE FIRST WEEK OF THE NEXT YEAR (Week 53 in 2016 and WEEK 1 in 2017 ) !

Here is how my table looks like

---

| Date      | YEAR | WEEK | StoreName | Number_Of_Vistors             |

---

Anyone how I can make a query that runs over all weeks in the three years?

This is how I wrote my query :

```
SELECT
    (base.Store_Visitors-lw.Store_Visitors)/lw.Store_Visitors AS VARIANCE
FROM
  `myproject` base
JOIN (
  SELECT
    *, extract(WEEK FROM (DATE_ADD(DATE(TIMESTAMP(date)) , INTERVAL 1 Week))) AS n_week

  FROM
    `myproject` ) lw
ON
  base.WEEK = (lw.n_week-1)
  AND base.YEAR = lw.YEAR
  AND base.DAYOFWEEK = lw.DAYOFWEEK

  AND base.Store_Name = lw.Store_Name
```

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  (2) Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: I'm using standard Sql on Bigquery :) ! Which tags were incompatible ? Thanks

Comment: Years generally have 52 weeks by the way. It may have 53 only if the first day of the year is a Thursday or, in a leap year, a Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

You need to row number your data by week and year and join on that or some other non-repeating value of your data.

```
SELECT
    (base.Store_Visitors-lw.Store_Visitors)/lw.Store_Visitors AS VARIANCE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Store_Name ORDER BY YEAR, WEEK) AS WeekOrder

FROM
  `BaseData` base
JOIN (
  SELECT
    *, extract(WEEK FROM (DATE_ADD(DATE(TIMESTAMP(date)) , INTERVAL 1 Week))) AS n_week,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Store_Name ORDER BY YEAR, WEEK) AS WeekOrder


  FROM
    `BaseData` ) lw
ON
  base.WeekOrder= lw.WeekOrder-1
  AND base.DAYOFWEEK = lw.DAYOFWEEK

  AND base.Store_Name = lw.Store_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and using analytic functions instead of self-joining

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.date) year, 
    EXTRACT(WEEK FROM t.date) week, 
    Store_Name, 
    Number_Of_Vistors
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
)
SELECT Store_Name, year, week, 
  (Number_Of_Vistors - ANY_VALUE(Number_Of_Vistors) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY Store_Name, year ORDER BY week RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
  ) / Number_Of_Vistors AS variance
FROM temp t
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2018-12-02' `date`, 'abc' Store_Name, 11 Number_Of_Vistors UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-12-09', 'abc', 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-12-16', 'abc', 33 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-12-23', 'abc', 44 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2018-12-30', 'abc', 55 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-06', 'abc', 66 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-13', 'abc', 77 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-20', 'abc', 88 
), temp AS (
  SELECT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.date) year, 
    EXTRACT(WEEK FROM t.date) week, 
    Store_Name, 
    Number_Of_Vistors
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
)
SELECT Store_Name, year, week, 
  (Number_Of_Vistors - ANY_VALUE(Number_Of_Vistors) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY Store_Name, year ORDER BY week RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
  ) / Number_Of_Vistors AS variance
FROM temp t
ORDER BY Store_Name, year, week
```

with result

```
Row Store_Name  year    week    variance     
1   abc         2018    48      null     
2   abc         2018    49      0.5  
3   abc         2018    50      0.3333333333333333   
4   abc         2018    51      0.25     
5   abc         2018    52      0.2  
6   abc         2019    1       null     
7   abc         2019    2       0.14285714285714285  
8   abc         2019    3       0.125
```

Note: as it is not clear from your question how exactly your data represented  - I am assuming you have one row per week, per year, per store

You should be able to adjust above as needed to your actual data types/ use case